# Alternative to Windows Home Server (WHS) backups

Tags: linux, windows-home-server

Since Microsoft announced the end of life for WHS, are there any alternatives?

Specifically, I am interested in recovering from a catastrophic disk failure with WHS.

For example, this is my ideal scenario when a desktop hard-drive fails (has a bad virus, etc):

1. Install a disk of the same size or greater
2. Boot the desktop with the Recovery Disc
3. Point the recovery application at the WHS
4. Pick the machine, the drive(s) and the date of the backup
5. Have a couple beers
6. Reboot to a working machine as if nothing happened.

I would need to slap multiple disks in the machine without raid.  It sounds like [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) will work here.

It would be nice, but not required to have de-duplication of files when multiple machines are backed up.  ([Single Instance Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-instance_storage))

Answer (score 0):

I  replaced my home server with [Amahi](http://www.amahi.org) for several reasons.  Among other things, Amahi is a app platform and one of those apps is the Redo Backup & Recovery tool.  From the description, it appears to do what you are looking for (although I don't recommend beer while performing a recovery-save it to celebrate).